# multiple instances of cucumber for 3000 scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber

I have a test pack consisting of more than 3000 scenarios.now the problem is that when i run the scenarios in one shot ..it takes approx 10 hours to complete,i want to divide the scenarios in 4 blocks,each of approx 750 scenarios and wanted to run them parallel in different windows/terminal(VMware).is there a workaround ???

Comment: What do you want to accomplish: minimizing the VM instances?  Consolidating your reporting? Running them from a central spot?

Comment: i want to run all the scenarios in multiple terminals consecutively in a pack of 500-700,so that the test executes immediately...instaed of executing 3000 in just one terminal and waiting for 15 hours  to end

Comment: You could try tddium. They will parallelize your test and then you won't need to fiddle with all of the database and selenium setup details that plague most parallel test implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a selenium tag, so (assuming that's accurate) [Selenium-Grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#selenium-grid-2-0) would be an option for setting up a distributed parallel testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

orde mentions Selenium Grid and that's one piece of the puzzle.  The main benefit you get out of that is that you only have to identify your Server Hub in your code when creating a new selenium instance.

The next thing would be to actually execute your 4 blocks of 750 scenarios at once.  I'd recommend using a CI tool like Jenkins to accomplish that and you'll have your results together on Jenkins' web gui.